# Excel Index Match with adjustable rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I am using Excel 2019 and I want to write a formula that will do the following:
search for a student name in Sheet1 (named classes) and for every class he/she took, update from Sheet2 (named Archive) the Code number.

Here is what the data looks like:
[Sample of Student Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTcwp.png)

If the number of classes was fixed for everyone, e.g. if every student had 1 class the answer would be to write something like:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C$3:C$21,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A$2:A$21,0),1)`

In our case however the number of classes may vary per student (e.g. John has 2 classes, Physics and Biology, while Helen has 4).

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Please create a screenshot with desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column to the archive sheet that puts the name of each student against each row.

In cell D2, I have this:

```
=IF(B2="",A2,D1)
```

Then for the formula to get the code, I have this in cell K2:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH($I2&$J2,$D$2:$D$9&$A$2:$A$9,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! That extra column really did the job !

Comment: @fkdiog32, u may press the tick button to indicate this question as 'answered' (:

Answer (score 0):

replace `Sheet2!C$3:C$21` with `INDIRECT("Sheet2!C$"&match(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A:A)&":C$21")`

and `MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A$2:A$21,0)` with `MATCH(Sheet1!B3,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A$"&match(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A:A)&":A$21"),0)`

pls share if it works/not/understandable..

Comment: Saddly INDIRECT did n't work for me . What worked was the proposed creation of an extra column ,made by "FlexYourData"  ,   then use in Cell Sheet1!C the formula :                            
       =INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(1,(A3=Sheet2!T:T)*(B3=Sheet2!A:A),0))

Comment: ok... glad u'd found a workable solution.. ( :